# Are you going to migrate some questions from stackoverflow or other sites to here because they better fit this site?

Tags: discussion, migration, scope

Today, I was looking at the oldest questions asked in other sites. Take **Geographic Information Systems** as an example:
[The site's age is 6y1m](http://stackexchange.com/sites#technology-oldest) and and as it is seen in [the area51 page of the site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425):

- [The definition phase has started on June 1th 2010.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/posts/1425/revisions)
- [The Commitment phase has started on June 14th 2010.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425?page=54&phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top)
- [The private beta phase has started on July 22th 2010.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425?page=1&phase=commitment&committers=mostrecent#tab-top)

And because that time the private betas last for only one week, probably the public beta started on July 29th 2010.
If you take a look to the oldest questions, you'll see that some of them have been asked even before July 22th 2010. [like this one which has been asked on August 9th 2009 and has been migrated from stackoverflow.com to GIS.SE.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/15541/19874)
Also if you cast a glance to [questions asked before July 29th 2011](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions?page=1431&sort=newest), you'll see that some of them has been migrated from another sites like superuser.com, etc.
I wanna see if you're going to migrate some questions from other sites to here in private beta?
Or it should be done after getting assured that private beta has ended successfully?
And how will the migration take place?

Answer (score 6):

No, that wouldn't happen. A site only becomes eligible as a migration target from other sites' close dialogs after it loses the "beta" label entirely. Also, questions older than 60 days [cannot be migrated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156255/295684), even by moderators! The migration you mentioned took place before that rule was instated.

Besides, a question being on-topic at the target site is not a sufficient reason to migrate it. It would have to be explicitly off-topic on the source too. (There's an exception for question owners who want their unanswered question moved: they can flag their post with a custom reason requesting migration.)

Answer (score 1):

Migration to and from this site, in private beta, is most likely not going to be done. You'd have to invite people to the community in order for them to see the question - and when it comes to migrating from this site, it's easier to just close and re-ask (provided there are no answers yet).

After private beta... well, I suppose you could post a comment on such an Stack Overflow question that their question might be better off at ai.stackexchange. But those would have to be some good questions, and they'd have to be served here better than at Stack Overflow.

As for the example question, I think such a migration wouldn't be helping all that much - it's already answered, and as you can see, after migration, not much else happened to the question. It seems it was moved because both the asker and the answerer have an established presence on the other site, and because it fits better there.

Migration is not something to do quickly.